# git, How to push local branch into the specific remote

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Could you explain how to push a local branch to a specific remote branch?

```
$ git branch -vv 
dev 4d46c96 [origin/dev] Merge branch '1783' into dev
dev_3_feature 226b914 second commit in dev_3_feature
dev_second_feature 6b5f10f second commit in dev_2_feature
master baf5fc0 [origin/master: ahead 1] master feature
* myFeature da5cc64 second commit in dev_1_feature
test 334cf7e commiting my super changes locally
```

1. I want my `DEV` features to be pushed into `origin/dev` and stay there as branches, how can I do that ?
2. What/where/how should I set up locally to push into `origin/dev` by default instead of `origin/master`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Update :

So, generally when you work with Remote, First of all you need to pull the repository or branch.

If its repository then

```
git pull origin
```

if its branch then

```
git pull origin <yourRemoteBranchName>
```

after you pulled it, it will be on your machine. Now your current branch is `yourRemoteBranchName`.

If you are new and want to know what "origin" is, then run command `git remote -v`. It is in a sense alias for github repository so you can remember it. It can be either origin or anything of your choice.

---

Now, you have above Remote branch, then you can create your local branch from that pulled remote branch. It will create a new local branch from your current Remote branch.

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

The remote branch is automatically created when you push it to the remote server. So when you feel ready for it, you can just do:

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

Where `<remote-name>` is typically `origin`, the name which git gives to the remote you cloned from. Your colleagues would then just pull that branch, and it's automatically created locally.

Note however that formally, the format is:

```
git push <remote-name> <local-branch-name>:<remote-branch-name>
```

But when you omit one, it assumes both branch names are the same. Having said this, as a word of **caution**, do not make the critical mistake of specifying only `:<remote-branch-name>` (with the colon), or the remote branch will be deleted!

So that a subsequent `git pull` will know what to do, you might instead want to use:

```
git push -u <remote-name> <local-branch-name>
```

As described below, the `-u` option sets up an upstream branch:

> For every branch that is up to date or
> successfully pushed, add upstream
> (tracking) reference, used by
> argument-less git-pull(1) and other
> commands.

If you want to merge directly with upstream branch,

```
git merge branchName
```

You can refer to this documentation : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging . It has pretty good examples.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do you mean that all the `feature_branches` im creating locally after the push will be tracked branches and all of them remotely will root from `origin` like `origin/my_feature_branch_1`, `origin/my_feature_branch_2` and i cant do `origin/DEV/my_feature_branch_1`, `origin/DEV/my_feature_branch_2` and so on

Comment: You can do it, You can create a branch from another branch. And you can use first command in my answer for that.

Comment: yes i made my local `feature_branches` with the command `$ git checkout -b dev_3_feature dev`, so locally my `dev_3_feature` belongs to local `dev` which is tracking remote `origin/dev` as you see from my branches list. now when feature made and commited locally how can i upload it to the remote `origin/dev`, so team lead can pull my `origin/DEV/super_feature` check it and if ok merge it to the `origin/dev`, but if not will say me like "fix here and there", so i can switch to my branch locally, fix something required and push it again to remote

Comment: Yes, you can push the code, and create a pull request from your repository access. If everything is fine then, it will be merged to your branch.

Comment: could you edit it again according to my feature branches but not just place holder names ? so, the work flow will look like: 1) switch to the `dev` branch 2) `git pull` to get all the latest changes from the remote `origin/dev` 3) creating new branch `super_feature` from the `dev`: `git checkout -b super_feature dev` 4) implementing something and commiting it `git commit -am "some description of the super feature"` 5) PROBLEM IN THIS STEP now i need to push my `super_feature` branch to the remote `origin/dev` : `git push -u origin/dev super_feature` if i do so fatal origin/dev not repository

Comment: complete error text: `$ git status`
On branch myFeature
nothing to commit, working directory clean
`$ git push -u origin/dev myFeature`
fatal: 'origin/dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

this is hosted on bitbucket and i made my own repository for the test purposes. so i have all the rights i need

Comment: you can push it using `git push -u origin yourlocalBranch` , -u option is necessary i wrote answer clearly. Don't write origin/dev , just push the code, and then u can create a pull request, and merge it to your branch. I hope you got now

Comment: but if i do just `git push -u origin myFeature` i see it is branched from the `master` `http://i.imgur.com/iWT5Wrd.png` but i have `dev` branch there `http://i.imgur.com/JuKDkL6.png` i want it to be under `dev`, not under `master` branch

Comment: Now, create a pull request to merge your branch with DEV. and if you have access then merge it. Done.

Comment: but initially push it under the dev impossible ?

Comment: that's not how it works in workplace, but sure you can use `git merge branchName`

Answer (score 5):

Switch to the dev branch locally and then push to the dev branch on the origin remote:

```
git checkout dev
git push -u origin dev
```

The `-u` option on `git push` sets upstream tracking such that when you are on the dev branch, `git push` and `git pull` automatically do the same thing as `git push origin dev` and `git pull origin dev`.

---

If I misunderstood your question and you want to push all your branches with "dev..." into their respective branches on origin, you can do the above step for each of those branches, or you can do `git push origin --all` to push *all* your branches to the origin remote. So on origin, you'd have `origin/dev`, `origin/dev_3_feature`, etc.

---

If I doubly misunderstood your question and you want to push all your branches with "dev..." into a single remote branch, well, I'd advise not doing that. It's probably best if you merge/rebase all your dev branches into one branch and then push that to origin. Let's say you want to use the one branch called `dev`:

```
git checkout dev
git merge dev_3_feature
git merge dev_second_feature
git push -u origin dev
```

After each merge, you might have to resolve merge conflicts, so be warned.

As a last note, you may want some more descriptive branch names for future feature branches, as names like `dev_second_feature` doesn't really tell you what the feature is.

Comment: thanks, but can i have `origin/dev/my_dev_branches` or git doesnt support kind of tree with many branches from other branches and so on ?
i want my `master` branch to be clean with the production version, but my new features to be under `origin/dev/my_feature_branch_1`, `origin/dev/my_feature_branch_2` and so on. so team lead can check my `feature_branches` and if they are ok then merge them into `origin/dev` it is possible ?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely can. Just check out the feature branch locally (`git checkout -b dev/some-feature`), commit some stuff, and push it (`git push -u origin dev/some-feature`).

Comment: `git push origin dev/dev_3_feature`
error: src refspec dev/dev_3_feature does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://blabla@itbucket.org/blabla/some.rep.git'